# Computer Stalls 5 minutes after cold boot

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, freeze

My computer stalls about 5 minutes after a cold boot.

I let it warm up, restart it and then it'll work fine until next cold boot.

Issue happens in XP, Win Vista and Win 7 (even happened during an os install). 
Haven't tried a linux on it, but its a safe bet that its not a software issue.

Previously in the same machine I had a bad RAM that manifest as errors while installing
software, and crashes during games.

Not Overclocked.

I'm assuming its either the power supply stability or a bad cap on the motherboard,
how can I diagnose which it is?

Thanks

Steven

Comment: The cheapest solution would replace the power supply.  If its bad then you solve the problem, if the problem is not solved, then you have in theory a better power supply.  If its a bad cap in the motherboard your only real solution to to replace the motherboard.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I diagnose a faulty power supply?](http://superuser.com/questions/55060/how-can-i-diagnose-a-faulty-power-supply)

Comment: So both of you believe that power supply is more likely the issue?