# low voltage POST only means battery problems?

Tags: power-supply, battery, power-management, voltage, cmos

No doubt the watch battery on the motherboard long since lost its juice.

However, I'm not quite sure what error I saw on boot, I think it was before `POST` and I think it mentioned "low voltage".  A quick [search](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/nGMq3zkVws/) of `dmesg` shows nothing with regards to "voltage", so it was *probably* before `POST`.

I'll do what's [feasible](https://superuser.com/q/55060/55747) with regards to looking at the power supply, but any suggestions?  It's a "mature" PC (meaning quite ancient with a retail value of zero or fewer dollars).

Comment: Why not simply change the CMOS battery… about a buck [$£€ 1] at any supermarket these days. If you have a flat battery, your CMOS/BIOS will reset to default values at every cold boot.

Comment: probably so @Tetsujin